# Setting Long text for textviews in listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

hi how to get this result  for listview rows?
i have Two  textviews and and one image view should be Right ride always.
if long text will come for textview1 it should be like this

```
        for small textfor textview1

        --------------------------
        |Textview1(23)      --->  |
        |                         |
        -------------------------- 


        for long  textfor textview1

        --------------------------
        |Textview1....(23)    --->|
        |                         |
        --------------------------
```

plz help me

Comment: set `android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:maxEms="23"
                                android:singleLine="true"` to your textview and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
 <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_email"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:maxEms="23"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

**Update:** Try to set like

```
android:maxLines="1" android:maxLength="10" android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Comment: hi i used this no result

Comment: @sravani try this `android:maxLines="1" 
    android:maxLength="10" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"`

Comment: hey thanq for ur responce i will try this

Comment: hi i used this one working but if long text for text view on it will be like  this sometexttttttttttttttt....(25) i need like this but not getting

Comment: it is comming like this sometextttt(23)

Comment: @sravani if text is exceed more then u r specify  Ems then it'll show `........` that's it.

Comment: hey above my textviews are posted plz check once i'm not getting proper result

Comment: MD I'VE posted above  plz modify

Comment: @sravani  android:maxEms="23" reduced this and try

Comment: @sravani can u post one snap for what u want? and what u got?

Comment: i don't have enough reputations to post snaps so i've menstion formate above means in my question

Comment: can u give your mail id  plz

Comment: hi i didn't get ur mail id

Answer (score 0):

add these property in textview.
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"